# xslt: Adding a child element in xsltproc ruins formatting

Tags: xml, xslt

Consider `bla.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rooty>
  <person>
    <age>42</age>
    <name>bob</name>
  </person>
  <person>
    <age>53</age>
    <name>doggo</name>
  </person>
</rooty>
```

And transform `moo.xslt`, adding to each person a cow:

```xslt
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

  <!-- Identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="person">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
      <cow>Bessy</cow>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Running it with `xsltproc moo.xslt bla.xml` seems to miss a newline (after `cow`):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rooty>
  <person>
    <age>42</age>
    <name>bob</name>
  <cow>Bessy</cow></person>
  <person>
    <age>53</age>
    <name>doggo</name>
  <cow>Bessy</cow></person>
</rooty>
```

I managed to work around this by manually injecting spaces using things like `<xsl:text>&#xA;    </xsl:text>`, but I'm sure this is not the way. I assume my XSLT is doing something stupid, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Unless there is mixed contents I have found that `xsl:output indent="yes"` work best with `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` to give a consistent indentation. I have checked your example with xsltproc, however.

Comment: Looks like this works. If you'd care to provide a full answer, I'll be happy to give you the credit of solving this :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless there is mixed contents (elements with text node as well as element children, that is not the case in your sample input) I have found that `xsl:output indent="yes"` works best with `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` to give a consistent indentation.

Comment: While this helps with my current example, in the real-life file it creates very unreadable XML. I'll try and come up with an example that doesn't work and report back